# extract data from array after specifying Upper/Lower limit using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, limit, extract

Is there any method to specify upper and lower limits and extract the data from the array?

or

Is there any function in Matlab available to extract data from the array which fall under specified limits?

For example:
I have made two sample plots and I have extracted the following data points

```
A=[1 2.2 4.3  5.3 12.0 34.1 43.3] %Time stamp values from the first plot
B=[1.4 7.6 35.2] %Time stamp values from the second plot
```

I take each timestamp value from plot B  and wanted to add+2.0 and -2.0 and specify them as upper/lower limit.
I wanted to find if the timestamp values of A fall under any of the upper/lower limits….

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tol = 2;
result = bsxfun(@ge,A(:).',B(:)-tol) & bsxfun(@le,A(:).',B(:)+tol);
```

The interpretation is: `result(m,n)` is 1 if the n-th point in `A` is within +/-`tol` of the m-th point in `B`, and 0 otherwise.

If you just want to know if each point of `A` is within the specified range of *any* of the points in `B`, use

```
any(result)
```

With your example data:

```
>> A = [1 2.2 4.3 5.3 12.0 34.1 43.3];
>> B = [1.4 7.6 35.2];
>> result

result =

     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0

>> any(result)

ans =

     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [ismemberf File Exchange submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23294-ismemberf).

It basically lets you check whether there are matching values within your tolerance.

**Example:**

Here is how you can use `ismemberf` assuming you have downloaded it and it is on your path:

```
A = [1 2.2 4.3 5.3 12.0 34.1 43.3] 
B = [1.4 7.6 35.2]
[lia, locb] = ismemberf(A,B,'tol',2)
```

Will give:

```
lia =

     1     1     0     0     0     1     0


locb =

     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
```